# Find tangent to a curve that pass through the origin (implicit function)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I am trying to find the number of tangents to a curve that all pass through the origin.
 The curve's equation is $y=x^3+x^2−22x+20.$ I also need to find the equation of said tangents.
My work:
Let's use formula for tangent line:
$$y-y_0=y'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$
We know that $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Let's find $y'(x_0)$:
$y'(x_0)=3x_0^2+2x_0-22$ 

Plugin what we know:
$$-y_0=(3x_0^2+2x_0-22)*-x_0$$
We aslo know that $y_0=x_0^3+x_0^2-22x_0+20$
$$-x_0^3-x_0^2+22x_0-20=-3x_0^3-2x_0^2+22x_0$$
$$2x_0^3+x_0^2-20=0$$
Only real solution is 2. $x_0=2$ and $y_0=-12$.
Let tangent line be $y=kx+l$.
$k=y'(2)=-6$
$-12=-6*2+l\to l=0$
But we want l to be zero. 
Our solution is $y=-6x$.
Ok, that was an easy problem but what about equaly problem by my function look like this: $x^2-xy+y^2-1=0$. My question is how to solve equaly problem but my function is implicitly and I can't easily solve for $y$

Comment: You can solve for $y$: that is a quadratic equation in $y$, so solve for it using completing the square or the quadratic formula. You will get two functions of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what about equaly problem by my function look like this: $x^2-xy+y^2-1=0$. My question is how to solve equaly problem but my function is implicitly and I can't easily solve for $y$

You want to find the number of tangents to a curve $x^2-xy+y^2-1=0$ that all pass through the origin.

Let $(s,t)$ be the tangent point on the curve, i.e. $$s^2-st+t^2-1=0\tag1$$

We have $$2x-y-xy'+2yy'=0\iff (-x+2y)y'=-2x+y$$ 
Suppose that $-x+2y=0$, then $-2x+y=0$. Hence, $x=y=0$ but this point is not on the curve. Hence, $-x+2y\not=0$.

So a line tangent at $(s,t)$ is given by
$$y-t=\frac{-2s+t}{-s+2t}(x-s)$$
Setting $x=y=0$ gives
$$0-t=\frac{-2s+t}{-s+2t}(0-s),$$
i.e.
$$s^2+t^2-st=0\tag2$$
However, there is no $(s,t)$ satisfying both $(1)$ and $(2)$. Hence, there is no such tangent.

---

In general, you would have two equations on two variables.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=x^3+x^2-22x+20$$

$$y'=3x^2+2x-22$$

WLOG any point of the $y=x^3+x^2-22x+20$ can be $t,t^3+t^2-22t+20$

The equation of the tangent at $t,$  will be $$\dfrac{y-(t^3+t^2-22t+20)}{x-t}=3t^2+2t-22$$

Put $x=y=0$ and solve for $t$

Comment: But wasn't the question asking about implicit functions?

Comment: @GoodDeeds, How do you define an "implicit function"?

Comment: A function not of the form $y=f(x)$, but rather $f(x,y)=0$?

Comment: @GoodDeeds, But the given function is of the form $y=f(x)$

Comment: But in the last two sentences as well as the title ask when the function is implicitly defined